# Update query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `Table1`. With fields `f1, f2`

The table values are like that (values contains quotes)

```
 "Hello1", "ok1"
 "Hello2", "ok2"
```

I need a update query so that it will remove the quotes from the values 
and it should  look like

```
 Hello1, ok1
 Hello2, ok2
```

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: There are a lot of SQL databases.. What database engine are you using? i.e. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc

Comment: @user310850 - Do we assume all of rows contain surrounding quotes?  Or only some?  Also, what version of SQL you're using?

Comment: @user310850 - What database product and version? I.e., MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: Just to clarify : do you want surrounding quotes to be removed?  or ALL quotes?

Comment: Hi to all ,iam using SQL Server and Quotes contains in all columns of all rows

Comment: @Chris Rogers   surrounding quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Replace function to strip out the double quotes.

```
UPDATE Table1 set f1 = REPLACE(f1,'"',''), f2 = REPLACE(f2,'"','');
```

Comment: Can you write the full query to get tthe out put that i required please

Comment: After you run the update it's just a matter of Selecting the columns:  SELECT f1, f2 FROM Table1

Comment: @user310850 that's the whole thing unless you want to add a where

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove only the surrounding quotes use :

```
UPDATE Table1 SET
f1 = SUBSTRING(f1, 2, LEN(f1)-2),
f2 = SUBSTRING(f2, 2, LEN(f2)-2)
```

If you want to remove all quotes (including middle ones) use :

```
UPDATE Table1 set f1 = REPLACE(f1,'"',''), f2 = REPLACE(f2,'"','')
```

Then to get the final output, you can use :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Table1
Set f1 = Case
            When f1 Like '"%' And f1 Like '%"' Then Substring(f1,2,Len(f1)-2)
            When f1 Like '"%' Then Substring(f1,1,Len(f1)-1)
            When f1 Like '%"' Then Substring(f1,2,Len(f1)-1)
            Else f1
            End
    , f2 = Case
            When f2 Like '"%' And f2 Like '%"' Then Substring(f2,2,Len(f2)-2)
            When f2 Like '"%' Then Substring(f2,1,Len(f2)-1)
            When f2 Like '%"' Then Substring(f2,2,Len(f2)-1)
            Else f2
            End
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might depend on the variety of SQL, but in MySQL you can do:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET f1 = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM f1), f2 = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM f2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [len](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) to get only a part of the string.

Use this update statement to change the content of your table

```
update Table1 set
  f1 = substring(f1, 2, len(f1)-2),
  f2 = substring(f2, 2, len(f2)-2)
```

If you only want to change the output of a query you can do this

```
select
  substring(f1, 2, len(f1)-2),
  substring(f2, 2, len(f2)-2)
from Table1
```